# Regulating 240 VAC down to 200 VAC

Tags: voltage, voltage-regulator

I'm designing a fryer machine, and we want to sell it over the world, and trying to minimize the problem of the different voltages, so we already asked our heaters supplier to custom make our heaters to 200 VAC (each heater is 8.5 kW and I will use 8 of them), now I need to buy a module that takes any range of voltage from 210 up to 260 VAC and regulate it to 200 VAC.
Any ideas what can I use for this purpose? I know about regulators, but we want something different and cost effective.

Comment: Have you heard of "triac dimmers"? You don't need full clean sinusoidal AC, chopped waveform will do just fine for heating purposes.

Comment: @AliChen . . many regions have regulations regarding power factor and harmonics.

Comment: Is there any temperature control, or do the heaters just stay on full power all the time?

Comment: To avoid problems regarding power factor and harmonics, you may use PWM (pulse width modulation) combined with zero crossing switching. Only full periods of the sinusoidal AC, no chopping of waveform. The full period PWM may be used for temperature control of the fryer oil as well as adaptation to the voltage range from 210 up to 260 VAC. 50 % of power will be about 1 second or 50 periods on and the same time off. Temperature control is slow, there is only a very small temperature change within 1 second.

Comment: @Jack B: I hope there will be no such powerful fryers without temperature control. Overheated oil may be very dangerous.

Comment: Of course there will be temperature control, in the prototype stage we are controlling the heaters by means of a PLC.

Comment: Use a 220 V nominal one which can withstand 260 VAC and take the “slack” on the thermostat duty cycle?

Answer (score 5):

In the comments, you say that these heaters are controlled by a temperature controller. In that case you can just spec up heaters which can manage 260V (230V countries with +10% tolerance, e.g. UK), and provides the required 8.5kW at 200V. You'll end up with something which can provide more like 12kW at 240V. You can then let the temperature controller turn it down as necessary.

With an overall power requirement of 68kW, you might also want to design the fryer to work with three phase power, which may only be available at higher voltages (if there is no neutral available). One common approach to this problem is to have several heater outputs each with two heaters. These are then connected in parallel for a 230V supply, and in series for a 400V supply. With six heaters in three pairs, you can distribute the load evenly between the three phases.

Comment: The downside of this approach is that the peak power consumption will be about 50% higher when running at 260V than at 200V. Depending on your installation scenarios this may or may not be a problem. A possible mitigation may be to design the controller to stagger the on periods of the heaters to reduce peak power draw.

Comment: Sorry about not mentioned that we are using three phase power, we are going to connect two heaters of 8.5 kW per vat, there are two individual vats and a third which is double (for a total of 8 heaters), we are using solid state relays to switch on and off the heaters, controlled by the PLC. And we are connecting three solid state relays (SSR) per vat, one for each phase and each SSR is controlling two heaters at the same time. We will also have sensors to know at every moment the temperature of the oil.

Comment: For balanced three phase power, 9 heaters, 3 per phase would be better. 8 heaters of 8.5 kW each will be one phase with 17 kW load and two phases with 25.5 kW load.

Answer (score 1):

There are options but they all have problems.

The cheapest is likely a "triac dimmer" that turns the load on and off during the cycle. The problem with this is you may run into regulatory issues selling it in some countries due to the poor power factor and substantial harmonics (the stage lighting industry still seems to be getting away with it though......).

Variable transformers are an option for converting voltage but are likely to be prohibitively expensive at these power levels.

More advanced active power electronics may be able to provide a soloution with good power factor but I doubt they will be cheap to design or build.

Ultimately I think your best option is probablly to review the heater design and design a heater with multiple taps so that the desired power level can be acheived at a variety of input voltages.

Or alternatively design your heater to tolerate the max possible input voltage and live with a variation in power level depending on location (as suggested in a comment make up for it in the duty cycle), I think your voltage range is a bit wide for this to be practical though.